# ListView which allows long press for contextual menu, yet also allow selecting text

Tags: android, listview, contextual-action-bar

I'm not sure if this possible, but I'd like to somehow have text on rows of a List to be selectable for copying but also, long press to bring up a contextual menu.

I know that long press is required for selecting individual text, but its being overridden by the fact that I need to apply a long press to the entire row for displaying the contextual menu.

I'm sure others have come across this problem?

Edit: Ok, I just realised text can be selected by not only Long press but also, double click/press. So that can be used in this case instead

Comment: See edit, I realised the text selection menu is started not only by long press on text but also on double press/click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    yourEditText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    yourEditText.clearFocus();
    yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            yourEditText.requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
    });
```